# Which optimizations do UDFs not benefit from?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, catalyst-optimizer

Spark UDF's contain the following functions: nullable, deterministic, dataType, etc.  So according to this information, it would benefit from optimizations such as ConstantFolding.  Which other optimizations does it benefit from and which optimizations can it not benefit from?  I ask this because many presentations present UDFs as a black box which does not benefit from catalyst optimizations, but clearly, it benefits from ConstantFolding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark handles UDF's by wrapping them inside of a class.  For example when you write the following:

```scala
val example = udf((a: Int) => a * 2)
```

What the `udf` function does is create a `UserDefinedFunction` class which in its apply function creates a `ScalaUDF.`  ScalaUDF extends Expression, and in its doCodeGen method it does the following:

```scala
...
    val callFunc =
      s"""
         |$boxedType $resultTerm = null;
         |try {
         |  $resultTerm = ($boxedType)$resultConverter.apply($getFuncResult);
         |} catch (Exception e) {
         |  throw new org.apache.spark.SparkException($errorMsgTerm, e);
         |}
       """.stripMargin

    ev.copy(code =
      code"""
         |$evalCode
         |${initArgs.mkString("\n")}
         |$callFunc
...
```

This function converts the `DataType` of the column/expression to a Scala type (because your UDF operates on scala types), and then it calls your lambda.  The `deterministic,` `nullable,` and `dataTypes` are functions of the wrapper of the user-defined function because it extends Expression, not your function.  If you want to fully benefit from them, you would have to write a custom Expression which extends `Expression` or one of its sub-classes.

Take the following as an example:

```scala
val redundantUdf = udf((a: Long) => true)
someDf.filter(redundantUdf(someDf("col1"))).explain()
```

The optimized logical plan would look something like this:

```
Project [_1#5736 AS Type#5739, _2#5737L AS sts#5740L]
 +- Filter UDF(_2#5737L)
  +- LocalRelation [_1#5736, _2#5737L]
```

As you can see it is doing the filter even though it is redundant and will always evaluate to true.

Whereas the following:

```scala
someDf.filter(expr("true")).explain()
```

would give the following optimized logical plan:

```
LocalRelation [Type#5739, sts#5740L]
```

It prunes out the filter using PruneFilter rule.

This doesn't mean all optimizations are excluded, there are optimizations which still work with UDFs such as `CombineFilter` which combines the expression from two filters for example:

```
== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
_1: string, _2: string
Filter UDF(_1#2)
+- Filter UDF(_1#2)
   +- LocalRelation [_1#2, _2#3]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Filter (UDF(_1#2) && UDF(_1#2))
+- LocalRelation [_1#2, _2#3]
```

This optimization works because it is only dependent on the `deterministic` field and UDFs are deterministic by default.  So UDFs will benefit from simple optimizations that aren't dependent on the function it wraps.  This is because it is in a format which catalyst doesn't understand, catalyst operates on Trees, and your closure is a Scala function.  There are other places where UDFs lose out such as specifying the java code generated and spark type information.